# Python Sequences Example

Tags: python, sequence

Im learning Python and we are on a lesson about sequences, we have been given this example code but I have a few questions about it;

```
word = input("Word? ")
letter = input("Letter? ")
i = 0
found = False
while not found and i != len(word):
    found = word[i] == letter
    i = i + 1
if found :
    print("letter ", letter, " found in word ", word, " at position ", i -1)
else:
    print("letter ", letter, " not found in word ", word)
```

1. What happens at the line found = word[i] == letter
2. Why does the print statement states a letter found at i-1

I am very new to this so if you could ELI5 that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the letter the program is looking at right now (`word[i]`) is equal to `letter`, the boolean variable `found` becomes `true`, otherwise, the loop will continue until the end of the word or until `letter` is found.
2. Because `i` has been incremented in the `while` loop above it, regardless of whether `letter` has been found or not.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped alot.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider marking the answer if this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to python. To answer your questions:

1. This statement assigns to `found` the value of the comparison
   between `word[i]` and `letter`. In other words, `found` takes
   the `boolean` value of the answer to the question:

   ```
   "is `word[i]` equal to `letter`?"
   ```
2. You use `i-1` instead of `i` because the loop is not prevented
   from incrementing `i` even when it was found.

Answer (score 0):

1. `found = word[i] == letter`: As you can see, in an earlier point in
   your program you set `found` to `False`. This type of variable is
   commonly called a "boolean flag". Inside your for loop, the value of
   `found` is set to the boolean expression `word[i] == letter`, which
   means in plain English: *If the value of `word` at index `i`, is
   equal to the value of the variable `letter` return true, otherwise
   return false*.
2. Inside your print statement, when the boolean flag `found`(see above answer) is true, it will print the index at which the match occurred. As you might have already learned, each character in each string has specific index. eg.

   ```
   >>> string = "string"
   >>> string[0] # what is the value of the character at postion zero?
   's'
   >>> string[1] # what is the value of the character at postion one?
   't'
   >>> etc..
   ```